# PHP to Coldfusion

Tags: php, cfml, pow

I need to convert the following line of PHP into Coldfusion

```
$age = 10
$test = pow($age,-2)*log($age);
```

Coldfusion does not have a POW() function. This is what I have come up with

```
<cfset age = 10>
<cfset test = age^-2*log(age)>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^` operator does the job

You are doing it right

Comment: ha ha, I'd get myself a tick if I could. Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score -1):

You're likely to notice performance and maintainability gains if you place this (and any sets immediately preceding or following) code within `cfscript`. Oh, and don't forget to scope your variables:

```
<cfscript>
   variables.age = 10;
   variables.test = variables.age^-2*log(variables.age);
</cfscript>
```